# Access saved model session object from controller into view

Tags: session, asp.net-mvc-5

I have saved a model into a session object in my controller but now I have no clue how to access it in my view.

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    using (DefaultConnection db = new DefaultConnection())
    {
        var model = from u in db.Users select u;
        Session["User"] = model;

        var vm = Session["User"] as User;
        return View(vm);
    }
}
```

I have tried this in my view but I am not experienced with MVC so I'm not sure how far off I am.

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.User>

@if (Model != null)
{
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <h1>item.Username</h1>
    }
}
```

Nothing shows up when I run it but I know for a fact there is data there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller:

```
public ActionResult Test()
    {
        using (DefaultConnection db = new DefaultConnection())
        {
            var model = from u in db.Users select u;
            Session["Users"] = model.ToList();
            return View();
        }
    }
```

In your View:

```
@(foreach(var item in ((List<User>)Session["Users"]))
{
    item.Username
}
```

If you want to make your view 'typed' with the class User then you have to send it to your view like :

```
 public ActionResult Test()
{
    using (DefaultConnection db = new DefaultConnection())
    {
        var model = from u in db.Users select u;
        return View(model.ToList());
    }
}
```

Include this directive in your View:

```
@model IEnumerable<SomeNamespace.User>
```

And then access your model with:

```
 @if (Model != null){
     foreach (var item in Model) {  item.Username }
 }
```

Comment: I tried it, using your second way because I liked it passed down from the controller. However I'm running into an error. When I try to do `@Model.Username` I get an error saying I need to check for null first. So I go ahead and do `@{ if (Model != null) { <h1>@Model.Username</h1> } }` but when I run it, nothing shows up. I know there's data in my table because if I run use the default Index action of the razor controller with read/write actions it lists all the entries.

Comment: I'm still getting nothing, let me update my question with my most current code and if you could take a look for an error I would appreciate it.

Comment: In your controller you're sending an IQueryable to yout view. Use the extension method 'ToList' to send a List<User> to your view. Then check if the property 'Username' of your users actually have any value.

Comment: Should I change `Session["User"] = model;` to `Session["User"] = model.ToList();`

Comment: You don't have to use the Session object in this case. Just send the list to the controller with return View(vm.ToList()) and remove the 'Session["User"] = model;' and 'var vm = Session["User"] as User;' lines

Comment: I do need it, because my database is being updated every 60 seconds and I need to have a details button so when they click details they still need to be able to see the details of the one they clicked, even if it disappears from the database while theyre still on the main page.

Comment: Ok, I've made a update. The first implementation uses Session and the second uses a typed View. Note that a query is being made every time you request the View so it will not keep showing deleted Users (this is a different problem).